# How do I use jQuery to fix a div to the top of the window only when the user scrolls down?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want the `my-sticky-element` to be pushed down by the top of the window when the user scrolls down, but only when the top of the window hits `my-sticky-element` as the user scrolls down. The code below does not seem to be pushing down the `my-sticky-element` (when I scroll down a few hundred pixels on my screen so that the top of the window collides with the element). I'm trying to do this in a SharePoint 2010 web part.

```js
//store the element
var $cache = $('.my-sticky-element');

//store the initial position of the element
var vTop = $cache.offset().top - parseFloat($cache.css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  // what the y position of the scroll is
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  // whether that's below the form
  if (y >= vTop) {
    // if so, ad the fixed class
    $cache.addClass('stuck');
  } else {
    // otherwise remove it
    $cache.removeClass('stuck');
  }
});
```

```css
.my-sticky-element.stuck {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.my-sticky-element {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

.container {
  /*container for centering element*/
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="my-sticky-element">I want this item to be pushed down whenever the top of the window hits it. It should be stuck to the top of the window until the user scrolls back up and makes room for it to be visible.
  </div>
</div>

<div style="height:1000px; width: 200px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
```

Comment: I edited your question adding the snippet. Could you please explain to me through running the snippet what should happen?

Comment: @quirimmo It behaves as indended in the code snippet, but when I try the same thing in my sharepoint page I cannot see the gray my-sticky-element as I scroll down. Any idea why Sharepoint 2010 won't express this code correctly?

Comment: have you tried to call your code inside the following method? `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myInitMethod");` this should be the method which add callbacks when share point loads pages. To check if the issue is related to a timing problem of loading the script, execute all your code inside a `setTimeout` with a delay of 5 seconds for example. If it works, the issue is when the code is executed. If it doesn't, the issue is somewhere else

Comment: p.s. I edited again your question adding the tags for share point and share point 2010. The issue is completely related with share point, there are no issues with jquery html and css, as the snippet proved

Comment: @quirimmo Ah ok. Do you know if there is any way to make a div like "my-sticky-element" behave so that it stops moving with the window once the scrolling makes it hit the bottom edge of the parent div, using CSS instead of jquery?

Comment: as I know nope, there is nothing of that available within CSS